# Which life is supported in sterilized 100% pure water?

Tags: microbiology, life

As sterilized 100% pure water does not contain any mineral and ion, so which type life can survive in sterilized 100% pure water?

Comment: Are you asking about what kinds of life can survive in 100% pure water, or what kinds of life can grow in 100% pure water?

Comment: If any living form is introduced to the system, that living should be able to survive without any external aid to support energy formation or supply.

Comment: If a lunged terrestrial animal is submerged in it, about a few minutes :-) this question needs more background and research to make sense.

Answer (score 2):

Of course many life forms can survive for some time in 100% water. A human for example can survive about 4 minutes in 100% water but I doubt this is what you are interested in! Although there is no commonly accepted definition of life, I think we can say that we all agree that any life form needs to reproduce or somehow grow. So I take your question as

> What life forms can reproduce or at least grow "potentially indefinitely" in 100% water?

Any life forms, to grow or reproduce needs matter to make its own constituents. As such, pure water won't provide with such nutrients and no life form can survive in the long run in 100% water.

Comment: by going in dormant stage or doing something magical to use the water for energy source. Or device some way to survive till their life expectancy?

Comment: Doing something magical :) Energy source is not so much the trouble as the could use solar energy. The main issue are the nutrients to create its own constituents. An organism cannot create a body part from water only. Sure, an organism can be dormant and survive in water for eventually a long time. However, I specifically explained why I would focus on life forms that can reproduce or at least grow in 100% water. Otherwise, pretty much all organisms, incl. humans, are able to survive some time (about 4 minutes for a human I think) in 100% water.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, 100% steril
ized means devoid of any kind of microbe, i. e,  bacteria, fungi or virus. But it very difficult to  ensure this. And if we could were able to produce such a pure water then also it's not completely safe. Since other than viruses there are other non cellular pathogens like prions (malicious proteins) which can thrive in a microbe free system.  But it is not to be counted as living.